# Levantar base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa, hibernate

tengo las clases en java cada una con sus anotations hechas para persistir , tengo configurado el persistance.xml en eso no tengo problema , mi problema es como hago para conectarlo con la base de datos mysql para que me cree las tablas ?

Comment: Hola Christian, bienvenido a la comunidad. Antes que nada, te invito a que te des una vuelta por esta [**presentación**] para que sepas como funciona este sitio. A continuación, me permito recomendarte esta guía para que puedes recibir una ayuda de forma más precisa: [_"Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable."_](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Mientras tanto aplicas las ediciones necesarias, marcaré tu pregunta en espera.

Comment: Existe una configuración para tu archivo persistence.xml donde puedes indicar que genere el DDL para tu base de datos. Aún así, no es algo que se recomiende, siempre es mejor generar el DDL mediante un dba o de manera personal y no confiar en la herramienta.